# How do I disable the Workspace Switcher in the Cinnamon environment I use with 12.04LTS?

Tags: workspaces, cinnamon, workspace-switcher

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Cinnamon DE on my laptop.

Whenever I  move the mouse cursor to the top left area of the screen, the workspace switcher comes up to offer multiple workspaces.

**How do I disable this?**  I don't want this to happen when I move the mouse cursor to the top left area of the screen. I prefer to have only one workspace for my use.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:  Go to **Cinnamon Settings**  select **"Hot Corner**  then un-check the **"Hot Corner enabled"** checkbox

See screen shots below

[image]

then
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded to Ubuntu 13+, You can run  `cinnamon-settings` then you should see *Hot Corner* icon & text, but if you don't, then it's in *Normal mode*.

To switch it to *Advanced Mode*, there is a new gears-like icon near the (new) search input field which you must click to see the *Normal* <-> *Advanced mode* switch.

Answer (score 0):

system setting -> window Tiling and Edge Flip -> cancel the check of "Enable Edge Flip" 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5643881/DeepinScrot-2205.png